# How could SAC achieve off-policyness?

Tags: reinforcement-learning

I'm studying SAC(Soft actor-critic) and I know it uses Q function estimation for policy evaluation and update.

But I wonder How it could achive off-policy, while other actor-critic algorithms like TRPO or PPO are on-policy.

Is it because SAC uses Q function, like DQN? Could anybody tell the reason in in-depth, relating to the definition and background knowledge of on and off policy?

I know off policy is made partly due to resolve the old dillema of "exploration & exploitation", by introducing 2 differenet policies where one is for generating data and the other is the target policy we want to learn, that will be the optimal policy in the end.

Thanks in advance.